# list manipulation in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with sublists in it. EG: (`[1, 2], [1, 56], [2, 787], [2, 98], [3, 90]`) which is created by appending values to it while running a for loop.

I am working in python, and i want to add the 2nd element of each sublist where the 1st elements are same. in my eg:
i want to add 2+56 (both have 1st index as 1), 787+98(both have 1st index as 2) and keep 90 as it is because there is just one element with 1st index as 3.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib, re
from itertools import groupby
import collections
import itertools, operator
text = urllib.urlopen("some html page").read() 
data = re.compile(r'.*?<BODY>(.*?)<HR>', re.DOTALL).match(text).group(1)// storing contents from the BODY tag
values = [line.split() for line in data.splitlines()] //List with the BODY data
/* values contain elements like [[65, 67], [112, 123, 12], [387, 198, 09]]
   it contains elements with length 2 and three. 
   i am just concerned with elements with length 3
   in the for loop, i am doing this, and passing it to 2 functions.*/

def function1 (docid, doclen, tf):
    new=[];
    avgdoclen = 288;
    tf = float(x[2]);
    doclen = float(x[1]);
    answer1 = tf / (tf + 0.5 + (1.5*doclen/avgdoclen));
    q = function2(docid, doclen, tf)
    production = answer1 * q //this is the production of 
    new.append(docid) // i want to add all the production values where docid are same.
    new.append(production)
    return answer1

def function2 (docid, doclen, tf):
    avgdoclen = 288;
    querylen = 12;
    tf= float(x[2]);
    answer2 = tf/(tf + 0.5 + (1.5*querylen/avgdoclen));
    return answer2

for x in values:
    if len(x)==3:
        okapi_doc(x[0], x[1], x[2])
        okapi_query(x[0], x[1], x[2])
```

I want to add all the production values where the docid are same. Now when i print new, i get the following output:

```
['112', 0.3559469323909391]
['150', 0.31715060007742935]
['158', 0.122025819265144]
['176', 0.3862207694241891]
['188', 0.5057900225015092]
['236', 0.12628982528263102]
['251', 0.12166336633663369]
```

this is not a list. when i print new[0][0] i get 1. I want to get 112 when i print new[0][0]. Is there something wrong with append?
    ['334', 0.5851519557155408]

Comment: Well the first thing I see is that in `function1`, you create `production` and `new` and then throw both away.

Comment: Append works fine. What do you think happens to `new` after the function exits? You have to return it and put it in a list to get a list of `new`s.

Comment: @ghbhatt: "new" obviously isn't the whole list, it's simply the temporary name you give to each of the 2-element lists there.  new[0] is the first entry, i.e. the string "112", and new[0][0] is the first character of that string, i.e. "1".  You're not actually accumulating anything, because as senderle notes, you throw it away.

Comment: Also, why are the semicolons in this code?

Comment: @DSM: I want to store the docids and production values in a new list. how can i do that? please help. I am new to python, and hence the syntax errors.

Comment: @senderle: i want to create a new array with all the docids and production values. how can i do it?

Comment: @senderle: how can i create a list which can store the tuples in the form [[docid, production], [docid, production],...]

Comment: Well, it depends on how you want to organize your code. But one simple approach would be to return `new` from `function1` instead of `answer1`. (I don't understand why you're returning `answer1`.) Then, assuming you have a list of `docid, doclen, tf` values, like so: `id_len_tf = [(docid, doclen, tf), (docid, doclen, tf), ...]`, create a list comprehension like so: `id_val = [function1(docid, doclen, tf) for docid, doclen, tf in id_len_tf]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(int) # works like a dictionary
# but all keys have a default value of zero
for key, value in mylist:
    result[key] += value 

print result
```

Comment: it gives me the following error: "for key, value in new_list:
ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Comment: Your first bit of code there won't work, since 'dict'-ing the list of lists has key collisions.

Comment: Your Counter example doesn't work. `dict` keeps only the last value for each key.

Comment: @ghbhatt, make sure all your "pairs" in the list are actually pairs. There's one item in there that contains three or more items.

Comment: @RobWouters: yes indeed there is. when i run the 1st version, i get the following error:  "print collections.Counter(dict(new_list))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required." but when i print len(new_list) it shows 2 for every element. i do not understand where the value is 3.

Comment: @ghbhatt, apparently the first element contains 3 values. Look closely.

Comment: @RobWouters: again, i printed len(new_list) and it shows 2 for every element. i am not able to find out elements with 3 values. is there any way i can check other then len?

Comment: @ghbhatt, You need to just `print(mylist)` and then look at the first tuple.

Comment: @ghbhatt: post the actual list?

Comment: @WolframH: i edited my question. i have printed the first few values. the list is too long with over 40k elements.

Comment: @ghbhatt: a) Does it work with that shorter list? b) Please copy & paste your source code, not some output. That is not a list (no surrounding brackets).

Comment: @WolframH: please see my edited question. i have posted my code.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a job for itertools:

```
>>> import itertools, operator
>>> l = sorted([[1, 2], [1, 56], [2, 787], [2, 98], [3, 90]])
>>> keys_groups = itertools.groupby(l, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
>>> sums = [[key, sum(i[1] for i in group)] for key, group in keys_groups]
>>> sums
[[1, 58], [2, 885], [3, 90]]
```

Note that for `groupby` to work as expected, the items have to be sorted by the key given. In this case, since the key is the first item in the pair, I didn't have to do this, but for a more general solution, you should use a `key` parameter to sort the list.

```
>>> l2 = [[787, 2], [98, 2], [90, 3], [2, 1], [56, 1]]
>>> l2.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> l2
[[2, 1], [56, 1], [787, 2], [98, 2], [90, 3]]
>>> keys_groups = itertools.groupby(l2, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> sums = [[key, sum(i[0] for i in group)] for key, group in keys_groups]
>>> sums
[[1, 58], [2, 885], [3, 90]]
```

Works fine with the data you posted. I edited it a bit to make the example more realistic.

```
>>> l = [['112', 0.3559469323909391], ['150', 0.31715060007742935], 
         ['158',0.122025819265144], ['176', 0.3862207694241891],
         ['188', 0.5057900225015092], ['377', 0.12628982528263102], 
         ['251', 0.12166336633663369], ['334', 0.5851519557155408], 
         ['334', 0.14663484486873507], ['112', 0.2345038167938931], 
         ['377', 0.10694516971279373], ['112', 0.28981132075471694]]
>>> l.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
>>> keys_groups = itertools.groupby(l, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
>>> sums = [[key, sum(i[1] for i in group)] for key, group in keys_groups]
>>> sums
[['112', 0.88026206993954914], ['150', 0.31715060007742935], 
 ['158', 0.122025819265144], ['176', 0.38622076942418909], 
 ['188', 0.50579002250150917], ['251', 0.12166336633663369], 
 ['334', 0.73178680058427581], ['377', 0.23323499499542477]]
```

Note that as WolframH points out, sorting will generally increase the time complexity; but Python's sort algorithm is smart enough to make use of runs in data, so it might not -- it all depends on the data. Still, if your data is highly anti-sorted, [Winston Ewert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145587/577088)'s `defaultdict`-based solution may be better. (But ignore that first `Counter` snippet -- I have no idea what's going on there.)

A couple of notes on how to create a list -- there are lots of ways, but the two basic ways in Python are as follows -- first a list comprehension:

```
>>> def simple_function(x):
...     return [x, x ** 2]
... 
>>> in_data = range(10)
>>> out_data = [simple_function(x) for x in in_data]
>>> out_data
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], [5, 25], [6, 36], [7, 49], [8, 64], [9, 81]]
```

And second, a for loop:

```
>>> out_data = []
>>> for x in in_data:
...     out_data.append(simple_function(x))
... 
>>> out_data
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], [5, 25], [6, 36], [7, 49], [8, 64], [9, 81]]
```

Comment: it gives me the following error: "sums = [[key, sum(i[1] for i in group)] for key, group in keys_groups]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @ghbhatt: please print out what your list is; this code should work perfectly.

Comment: sorting increases the time complexity from O(n) to O(n log n).

Comment: @ghbhatt: those terms work fine with this code, you're missing something.  Could you post the results of set(tuple(map(type, x)) for x in whatever_your_list_is_called)?  Something there isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @WolframH, good point. But it does depend on the data; [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is pretty clever about taking advantage of runs in semi-sorted data.

Comment: @senderle: i have posted my code for your review. please correct me where i am wrong.

Comment: Assuming this all works correctly, I think it makes more sense to create a dict at the end: `sums = dict((key, sum(i[1] for i in group)) for key, group in keys_groups)`

Comment: @ghbhatt, I edited my answer to explain how to create a list of lists.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straightforward. `dict.get(key, default)` returns the value if the key exists, or a default.

```
totals = {}
for k,v in data:
    totals[k] = totals.get(k, 0) + v
```

Comment: Your code is the same as: `from collections import defaultdict;totals = defaultdict(int); for k, v in data: totals[k] += v`

Comment: And based on the comments to questions below, your version and my modification will not work.

Comment: @hughdbrown, you're misunderstanding the comments. They're referring to the `Counter`-based solution. The `defaultdict`-based solution is correct.

Comment: @senderle -- interesting. I thought that `Counter` was just a python 2.7 specialization of collections.defaultdict(int).

Comment: @hughdbrown, it is, but `Counter` just counts instances of a particular key in a flat sequence. It doesn't do any summation or anything like that. In other words, for `Counter` to be helpful here, you'd have to pass it a list like this: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3....]`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you:

> want to add the 2nd element of each sublist where the 1st elements are same

makes me think that you want to be using a dict rather than a list - a dict is optimised for retrieving the 2nd value based on the 1st

Some code along the lines of:

```
oldvalue = mydict.get(firstvalue, 0)
newvalue = oldvalue + secondvalue
mydict[firstvalue] = newvalue
```

would let you build up the dict as you go - or if that's not feasible, it will let you calculate the sums in only a single pass over the list.

Quick spin in the interpreter just to test this out:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2], [1, 56], [2, 787], [2, 98], [3, 90]]
>>> mydict = {}
>>> for firstvalue, secondvalue in l:
...   oldvalue = mydict.get(firstvalue, 0)
...   newvalue = oldvalue + secondvalue
...   mydict[firstvalue] = newvalue
... 
>>> print mydict
{1: 58, 2: 885, 3: 90}
```

Looks fairly close to what you want.